# Angularjs Filter generating error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm applying a filter to an ng-repeat:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in acns | filter:isActive=true">
```

It works, but is generating an error:

Error: filter:notarray

Which seems strange to me, as it is returning an array.

Comment: what you wanted to do? and what you were doing?

Comment: Hi Pankaj. I am simply displaying just the results that have isActive = ture. Pretty straight forward.

Comment: Look at the answer which I;ve added

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is only the error then this can work:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in acns | toArray:false | filter:isActive=true">
```

Comment: Thanks gettingLearned for the input, but this does not work as it cannot find a provider associated with the toArray. Is there something I need to inject?

Answer (score 0):

Found a custom filter that made gettingLearned's "toArray:fals" answer work:

```
app.filter('toArray', function () {
'use strict';

return function (obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof Object)) {
        return obj;
    }

    return Object.keys(obj).filter(function(key){if(key.charAt(0) !== "$") {return key;}}).map(function (key) {
        return Object.defineProperty(obj[key], '$key', {__proto__: null, value: key});
    });
};
```

});

Thanks all!